# How do I add spaces between

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a page like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to add a set of numbers (not strings) when I press the button "set number list", but those numbers have to have spaces between them. I have all the HTML stuff I need, but I can't seem to figure out this JavaScript part. I know I can add numbers like this:

```
document.getElementById("listNumberButton").value = 1234;
```

and the result will show in the box when I click the button but I have done so much searching I can't seem to figure out how to add numbers with spaces between them like this:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to string, split it on `''`, and join it with space - i.e.

```
var number = 1234;
var spacedNumber = number.toString().split('').join(' ');
```

or, in your case

```
document.getElementById("listNumberButton").value = 1234..toString().split('').join(' ');
```

note the `..` due to Numbers having a decimal point :p

Comment: oops, left out the () for toString :p

Comment: Thank you so much. Also another question. how do u program, let's say: I want the computer to see if something, the typed value is a number, if so add that value.

Comment: javascript has a `parseFloat` and `isNaN` functions that can help

Comment: Note that while some users are generous and patient, StackOverflow isn't there to teach you the basics, so others might turn you down quickly. The MDN guide is a good place to start. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: works well

```
 var number="1234";
 number=number.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{1})/g, '$1 ').trim();
 answer will be 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man but I might not use this one because it doesn't make sense to me. I have not been introduced to the concept of "[^\dA-Z]/" and the dollar signs so it's really confusing to me

Comment: but even though if you are not aware of that, finally you will get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Run this snippet and check:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
 var number=document.getElementById("split").value;
  number=number.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{1})/g, '$1 ').trim();
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=number;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="split" onkeyup="myFunction()">
<h1 id="result"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell me what this laugage with words like " /[^\dA-Z]/" and dollar signs is called? I am only familiar with javascript

Comment: **you can see in the javascript code only in the above code..**
/[^\dA-Z]/ is a regular expression  and $1 is for after each digit to give space